# Database Driver class of IBM DB2 for codeigniter 2.x or 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, db2, driver

I am doing a project using `Codeigniter` with database `IBM DB2`. As there is no inbuilt `DB2 Driver package` for Codeigniter, I am using my own custom class. So that I can't use the active record functionality.

**Is there any way to work with IBM DB2 in Codeigniter with active record support?**

Any help could be appreciated. Thank you..

Comment: hm doesnt it work with PDO?
Take a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.connection.php

Comment: @sintakonte, No.. it doesn't. I had tried many solutions including PDO in codeigniter. None do the trick..